# Swift - How to call swift function with ENUM parameter from Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, function, swift, enums

I created a Swift class for a notification view (UIView) that has an ENUM setup for the type of notification to be set (i.e. for defining colors, text, etc for the different predetermined types of notifications).

I need to be able to call this from my existing Objective-C class, but whenever I put the ENUM in the Swift function arguments, Objective-C can't find that specific function (it is even removed from the "-Swift.h" file.

Is it possible to do this?

Here is my Swift Function:

```
enum NotificationViewType: Int
{
    case Custom = 0
    case Success
    case Error
    case Warning
}

init(inViewController: UIViewController, forType: NotificationViewType, duration: Float = 0.0, leftButtonHandler: () -> Void, rightButtonHandler: () -> Void)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find anything that explicitly says Swift enumerations are not supported in Objective-C, but a quick glance over their documentation shows that they are a feature of Swift that is quite alien to C-style enumerations.

Your best bet for an interoperable enumeration is to declare it first in Objective-C and then use it in both languages.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/swift/conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13) in the documentation on using C enumerations in Swift. I could find no comparable documentation talking about Swift enumerations in (Objective-)C.

Comment: The docs explicitly state that Swift enumerations are *not* accessible in Objective-C, see the answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: @MartinR Excellent. I wasn't saying they didn't, I was just saying that I couldn't find it.